# How to know the existing Sort Order of Admin menus?

Tags: admin, menu, sorting

I started with creating a custom module. 
When creating the ADMIN part for that module, I came across `<sort_order>` tag, which is responsible for placing the menu (I guess).
Coming to my question here is how to know the sort order of existing Menus, so that I can place my menu in first or last position or may be in middle position. Is their any way to determine the existing Menus ordering?

Below is my code `adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <helloworld translate="title" module="helloworld">
            <title>HelloWorld Admin</title>
            <sort_order>95</sort_order> <!-- I have just given some random number, and it placed my menu at last position :) -->
            <children>
                <helloworld translate="title" module="helloworld">
                    <title>SubMenu 1</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>perficient/helloworld/index/test</action>
                </helloworld>
            </children>
        </helloworld>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look in the proper `adminhtml.xml` file that adds a menu close to the one you want to add one.
Let's say you want to add a menu between `Sales` and `Catalog` main menus.
This means you have to look for the proper `adminhtml.xml` files that add the menus mentioned above.
By the name of the menus you should look in `Mage_Sales` and `Mage_Catalog`.
You will find in `Mage/Sales/etc/adminhtml.xml` this

```
 <menu>
     <sales translate="title" module="sales">
        <title>Sales</title>
        <sort_order>20</sort_order> 
        .....
```

and in `Mage/Catalog/etc/adminhtml.xml` this

```
<menu>
    <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
        <title>Catalog</title>
        <sort_order>30</sort_order> 
        ....
```

this means that any value you give for your menu's `sort_order` between 21 and 29 (included) will place your menu between these 2.

Comment: Whoa , wonderful mate !  <sort_order> 1 Thanks Much </sort_order> :)

Comment: @Marius what if my module doesn't have **adminhtml.xml** file? then is there any way for me to do this?